# Is there a Drupal language switcher that will only link to front page of the language?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules

In Drupal, the language switcher will by default link to the matching translated page of the current language page.  Would it be possible to have a block that would only link to the front page of the clicked language instead of the translated page/content? It would be great if there is a module that achieve this functionality....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure there is a module for this, what you can easily do is create a new block and enter html content:

```
<p><a class="active" href="/nl">NL</a> | <a href="/en">EN</a> | <a href="/fr">FR</a></p>
```

if you start your link with a / than Drupal will go to the root of the site.
You can then easily position the block in any region you want and allow users to change the language

Hope this helps.